# im trying to change my config file in vite in treminal but i got error (vite not one of the commands)

Tags: vue.js, vite

npm vite --config vite.config.js form-validation

im trying to change my config file in treminal but i got error that it must be one of those commands instead of vite word

access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
whoami

Comment: Did you mean `npx`?

Comment: no ... i want to change the location of main html file

Comment: Not sure to understand what you're trying to do here. Creating a new project (with `npx`) or passing a specific setting to Vite (no need for `npm` here in that case).

Comment: @HossamThapet `npm CMD` is the syntax to run an **npm** command by name. There is no such command named `vite`, as you can see from the list of actually available npm commands in the resulting error message. Also note that there is no command at all (in Vite's context) to modify the Vite config from the command line.

Comment: @tony19 on vite documentaion (vite --config my-config.js) put its not working in treminal so i added npm before it .... if i want to change the location of my main index.html file how i can do it without treminal

Comment: The `--config` parameter specifies the location of the config file to load. It doesn't change the config itself. And adding `npm` before the `vite` command was evidently a wild guess, as you pointed out.